# SSRS Not showing all column labels

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an issue with SSRS, I cannot see some other labels

This is how it looks like on design view

[image]

And at preview-time

[image]

The code behind it

```
SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN tr.TestOverallResult = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Failures,
        SUM(CASE WHEN tr.TestOverallResult = 0 THEN 1 END) AS Successes,
        5 as test

    FROM
        dbo.TestResults tr
    WHERE
        tr.MethodCode LIKE '%' + @MethodName + '%'
```

Any idea where's the problem ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a values group issue, change the order of the values, the label will disappear, right click to add it back, rinse and repeat for each one of your value sets. Then run the report and it will show them.